# Pandas: expand list in column to distinct rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a big number of columns that contain several values (imported from google forms, those are columns allowing multiple selection). I've imported those as lists initially.

Now I want to analyse the data based on some values from those columns, i.e. given

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[(1,2),(2,3),(1,)], b=[(1,3),(2,5),], c=['a','b','c']))

        a       b  c
0  (1, 2)  (1, 3)  a
1  (2, 3)  (2, 5)  b
2     (1)      ()  c
```

I want to plot a bar chart where X would be distinct values from columns a and b (they share the same set of options), and Y would be the total count of rows having the option:

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: thanks, I re-wrote the question to include context.

Comment: And I re-wrote it again to specify what I *actually* want to get. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by summing the columns (basically concatenating the contents) and then calling `pd.value_counts` on them. For example (modifying your dataframe definition slightly so it will not raise an error):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[(1,2),(2,3),(1,)],
                       b=[(1,3),(2,5),()],
                       c=['a','b','c']))
counts = pd.DataFrame({col: pd.value_counts(df[col].sum())
                       for col in ['a', 'b']})
counts.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

---

(previous answer to the original version of the question):

You can get all the rows where `2` is in `a` using a map, e.g.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]], b=['a','b','c']))
>>> df
        a  b
0  [1, 2]  a
1  [2, 3]  b
2  [1, 3]  c

>>> df[df.a.map(lambda L: 2 in L)]
        a  b
0  [1, 2]  a
1  [2, 3]  b
```

You could accomplish something similar using a `groupby` followed by a `filter`, though you first have to convert the `a` values to a tuple so that they're hashable (and can be group keys):

```
>>> df.groupby(df.a.map(tuple)).filter(lambda group: 2 in group.name)
        a  b
0  [1, 2]  a
1  [2, 3]  b
```

Once you have either of these results, you can use, e.g. `result['a'] = 2` to replace the values in the `a` column.

Comment: Reading the answer I realised that I lost the actual thing I try to achieve while editing. Can you please take another look?

Answer (score 1):

We can use Boolean indexing to filter records with don't have `2` in column `'a'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[[1,2],[2,3],[5,6]], b=['a','b','c']))

df
Out[16]: 
        a  b
0  [1, 2]  a
1  [2, 3]  b
2  [5, 6]  c

df[df.a.apply(lambda x: 2 in x)]
Out[17]: 
        a  b
0  [1, 2]  a
1  [2, 3]  b
```

Comment: Sorry for the noise here. I mistakenly edited this answer instead of my own answer. I've reverted the changes.